# Setting up Query() method using Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have my code setup in the [following way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx). I'm trying to test a method that should load some related collections only if requested, it also filters out some data based on defined parameters. My tests pass if I exclude the following code that is used to set a count property on the object:

Classes

```
 public class Foo
 {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set}
 }

 public class Bar
 {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    // ...
 }
```

DbContext

```
 ..
  public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foo {get;set;}
 ..
```

Repo

```
 public List<Foo> GetFoo(bool loadBar = false)
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> foos = Context.Foo.AsEnumerable();

    foreach (Foo f in foos)
    {
        // ...
        if (loadBar)
        {
            Context.Entry(foo).Collection(c => c.Bars).Load();
        }


        foo.Count = Context.Entry(foo)
                        .Collection(c => c.Bars)
                        .Query() // <-- Throws InvalidOperationException
                        .Count();

        // do some other filtering ...

        return foos.ToList();
    }
}
```

Test Methods

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void Test()
 {
     Mock<DbContext> mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
     Mock<DbSet<Foo>> fooMockSet = MockDbSet(new FooWithAtLeast1BarInCollection());

     mockContext.Setup(c => c.Foo)
        .Returns(fooMockSet.Object);

    using(repo)
    {
      List<Foo> foos = repo.GetFoo();
    }

 }

 public Mock<DbSet<T>> MockDbSet<T>(List<T> data) where T : class
{
    var queryable = data.AsQueryable();

    var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());

    return dbSet;
}
```

This works fine when I run the code, but my mocking can't be setup right as I receive the following exception:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'Query' cannot be called for property 'CollectionToCount' because the entity of type {'ParentType'}
>   does not exist in the context*

How can I setup Moq so that this will work? I have this so far, but I'm not sure what it should return:

```
mockContext.Setup(x =>
x.Entry(It.IsAny<T>())
.Collection(c => c.CollectionToCount))
.Returns(???);
```

Comment: There is currently not enough information provided. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. That will help when trying to identify the cause and hopefully aid in formulating a solution.

Comment: Hi, I tried to keep this concise as possible as my code is working apart from when attempting to mock the code posted. I simply want to be able to mock the call to the Query method for a related collection.

The collection is not always loaded, but the count of items in the collection (entity.CountProperty) should always contain the value regardless if the collection is loaded. This works, but not while I am mocking the data during testing.

Comment: I've added more information, this is __almost__ exactly how mine is setup.